# Relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c, assembly, linker, binutils

I know that when i use -pie this error will not come but this error is coming for only some relocation types these are

```
R_X86_64_32:
R_X86_64_8:
R_X86_64_16:
R_X86_64_32S:
```

I want to know why this error is coming for these types of relocations? are there any issues with relocation overflow while using position independent code?

Comment: These are absolute relocations which are simply not allowed.

Comment: Do you mean no error when you use `-no-pie`?    On some distros, `-pie` and `-fpie` are on by default.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux.